# How to delete an IP route?

Tags: networking, route

How to delete a route like the one below from a UNIX server?

```
122.252.228.38/255.255.255.255  122.252.228.38     UH        0  lan4       4136
```

Comment: What Unix is this on. It may differ depending on Unix flavour.

Comment: Please also add the command that you used to generate this output.

Answer (score 36):

You haven't included which system you're on or which tool-set you're using, but the two most common commands for managing the routing tables are the `route` and `ip` commands.

Here is how you might remove the route by using the `route` command (from the [net-tools](https://network-tools.com/) package):

```bsh
route del -net 122.252.228.38 netmask 255.255.255.255
```

And here is how you might delete the same route using the `ip` command (from the [iproute2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iproute2) package):

```bsh
ip route del 122.252.228.38/32
```

Answer (score -4):

```
sudo ip route del 122.252.228.38/32   # or any valid selector
```

```
sudo ip addr flush dev DEVICE    # then flush the cache and the route will be gone
```

Comment: Do not follow this advice, it will nuke all entries for a specified devices and will likely ruin your day/week/month, potentially locking your out of the system your are managing, and require an on-site console. `sudo ip addr flush dev DEVICE` is WAY too greedy for the problem at hand! The question just wants to remove a single entry! `flush` (as written) will remove ALL ENTRIES for a device!!!!!

Comment: DO NOT FOLLOW THIS ADVICE! The second command will RUIN YOUR DAY! DO NOT EXECUTE IT, it will literally remove all your route table entries!